# Every finite abelian p-group is isomorphic to a product of cyclic groups of p-power order in Abstract Algebra: A first course by Dan Sarasino

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I am teaching myself abstract algbera with the book `Abstract Algebra: A first course by Dan Sarasino`.

At `section 14`, `14.1`, the author proves every finite $p$-group is isomorphic to a product of cyclic groups of $p$-power order

**Essential details**:

Given a finite abelian $p$-group $G$ with order $|G| > 1$, choose $x \neq e$ and let $A = \langle x \rangle$ being the cyclic group generated by $x$.
By the induction hypothesis, i.e any group with order less than $|G|$ can be decomposed into a direct product of cyclic groups of $p$-power order.

$$
G / A \cong \langle y_1 \rangle \times \langle y_2 \rangle \times \ldots \times \langle y_m \rangle
$$

where $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m$ have orders $p^{t_1}, p^{t_2}, \ldots, p^{t_m}$ for some integers $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_m$

**The part I don't understand**

The author claimed that every element in $G / A$ has a unique representation

$$
(Ax_1)^{r_1} (Ax_2)^{r_2} \ldots (Ax_m)^{r_m}
$$

with $0 \leq r_i < p^{t_i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq m$

Wouldn't the unique representation of element in $G / A$ being the $m$-tuple of $y_i^{r_i}$? How did the author derive the product representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inductive hypothesis gives

$$
G / A \cong \langle y_1 \rangle \times \langle y_2 \rangle \times \ldots \times \langle y_m \rangle
$$

The author's notation is then tacitly identifying an internal direct product with an external direct product.
What this means is that we can choose $x_i \in G$, such that under the above isomorphism, $x_iA \in G/A$ corresponds to $(y_1^0, \ldots, y_{i-1}^0, y_i, y_{i+1}^0, \ldots, y_m^0)$ in $\langle y_1 \rangle \times \langle y_2 \rangle \times \ldots \times \langle y_m \rangle$. Then $(Ax_1)^{r_1} (Ax_2)^{r_2} \ldots (Ax_m)^{r_m}$ corresponds to $(y_1^{r_1}, \ldots, y_m^{r_m})$ and expressions of this form in the $x_i$ and $r_i$ will give unique representations of each element of $G/A$ subject to the given restrictions on the $r_i$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir